# How do I cut a string based on digit first certain digit and the rest

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

How do I cut a string based on digit first certain digit and the rest

Here's my data

```
Id       actual_pattern
1                100101
2                 10101
3               1010101
4                   101
```

Here's the expected output

for `cut_pattern1` is the first 4 digits from `actual_pattern`
for `cut_pattern2` is the rest form from  `cut_pattern1`, if the rest from  `cut_pattern1` is not exist make `cut_pattern2` = 0

If any `1` in `cut_pattern2`, make `binary_cut2` = 1 else make `binary_cut2` = 0

```
Id       actual_pattern   cut_pattern1       cut_pattern2    binary_cut2
1                100101           1001                 01              1
2                 10101           1010                  1              1
3               1010101           1010                101              1
4                   101            101                  0              0
```

Comment: And what is `binary_cut2`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create new columns by indexing with `str`, `replace` for change empty strings and for new column use [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with casting to integers:

```
df['actual_pattern'] = df['actual_pattern'].astype(str)

df['cut_pattern1'] = df['actual_pattern'].str[:4]
df['cut_pattern2'] = df['actual_pattern'].str[4:].replace('','0')
df['binary_cut2'] = df['cut_pattern2'].str.contains('1').astype(int)
print (df)
   Id actual_pattern cut_pattern1 cut_pattern2  binary_cut2
0   1         100101         1001           01            1
1   2          10101         1010            1            1
2   3        1010101         1010          101            1
3   4            101          101            0            0
```

EDIT:

Solution for @Rick Hitchcock from comments:

```
df['actual_pattern'] = df['actual_pattern'].astype(str)

df['cut_pattern1'] = df['actual_pattern'].str[:4]
df['cut_pattern2'] = df['actual_pattern'].str[4:].replace('','0')
df['binary_cut2'] = df['cut_pattern2'].str.contains('1').astype(int)
print (df)
  Id actual_pattern cut_pattern1 cut_pattern2  binary_cut2
0  1         100101         1001           01            1
1  2          10101         1010            1            1
2  3        1010101         1010          101            1
3  4       00001111         0000         1111            1
```

Comment: Curious why `.replace('','0')` is needed?

Comment: @RickHitchcock - Because `str[4:]` return empty string

Comment: But it won't always return an empty string, and when it doesn't, wouldn't it change '1111' to '01010101'?

Comment: @RickHitchcock - Why do you think so?

Comment: `'00001111'[4:].replace('', '0')` returns `010101010`

Comment: @RickHitchcock - in pandas not.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I'd approach this:

```
s = df.actual_pattern.astype(str).str
# Split into 2 lists, the first containing the first 4 digits
out = s.split(r'(\d{4})').str[-2:].values.tolist()
# [['1001', '01'], ['1010', '1'], ['1010', '101'], ['101']]
# build a dataframe from the lists
out = pd.DataFrame(out, columns=['cut_pattern1', 'cut_pattern2'])
# fill missing values (absense of string in list) with 0
out['cut_pattern2'] = out.cut_pattern2.fillna('0')
out['binary_cut2'] = out.cut_pattern2.str.contains('1').view('i1')
print(out)

     cut_pattern1 cut_pattern2 binary_cut2
0         1001           01           1
1         1010            1           1
2         1010          101           1
3          101            0           0
```

Answer (score 2):

Using some regex and string extract here:

```
m=df.actual_pattern.str.extract('(?P<cut_pattern1>.{,4})(?P<cut_pattern2>.*)').replace('',0)
```

---

```
   cut_pattern1 cut_pattern2
0         1001           01
1         1010            1
2         1010          101
3          101            0
```

Then do:

```
m.assign(binary_cut2=m.cut_pattern2.str.contains('1',na=False).astype(int))
```

---

```
  cut_pattern1 cut_pattern2  binary_cut2
0         1001           01            1
1         1010            1            1
2         1010          101            1
3          101            0            0
```

Finally concat this to the original df:

```
m=df.actual_pattern.str.extract('(?P<cut_pattern1>.{,4})(?P<cut_pattern2>.*)').replace('',0)
m=m.assign(binary_cut2=m.cut_pattern2.str.contains('1',na=False).astype(int))
pd.concat([df,m],axis=1)
```

---

```
  Id actual_pattern cut_pattern1 cut_pattern2  binary_cut2
0  1         100101         1001           01            1
1  2          10101         1010            1            1
2  3        1010101         1010          101            1
3  4            101          101            0            0
```